# How to read multiply char arrays from a file in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function, file

The file "Athlete info.txt" looks like this:

```
Peter Gab 2653 Kenya 127

Usain Bolt 6534 Jamaica 128

Bla Bla 2973 Bangladesh -1

Some Name 5182 India 129
```

What I expect my code to do is read the first string and assign it to the `firstName` array (for eg Peter is stored in `firstName[0]`), read the second string and assign it to `lastName` array ( for eg Gab is stored in `lastName[0]`) and so on..I've tried many different ways and even tried making it all string arrays but it doesn't work. If anyone can tell me what's wrong in the code or how to go about it, that would be great!

Thanks in advance!

```
void readInputFromFile()
    {
        ifstream inputData;
        inputData.open("Athlete info.txt");

        const int SIZE=50;
        char firstName[SIZE],
             lastName[SIZE],
             athleteNumber[SIZE],
             country[SIZE];
        int  athleteTime[SIZE];

        int numOfCharacters=0;

        if (inputData.is_open())
        {
            int i=0;

            while(!inputData.eof())
            {
                inputData >> firstName[i]; 
                inputData >> lastName[i]; 
                inputData >> athleteNumber[i];
                inputData >> country[i]; 
                inputData >> athleteTime[i];
                i++;
                numOfCharacters++;
            }

            for (int i=0; i < numOfCharacters; i++ )
            {
                cout << "First Name: " << firstName[i];
                cout << "Last name: " << lastName[i];
                cout << "AthleteNumber: " << athleteNumber[i];
                cout << "Country: " << country[i];
                cout << "Time taken: " << athleteTime[i];
                cout << endl;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            cout << "ERROR" << endl;
        }
        inputData.close();
    }
```

Comment: `while(!inputData.eof())` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: You are reading 1 character. instead of a string. This code would be cleaner and better if you were permitted to use `c++`. I mean std::string instead of a c-array for the strings..

Answer (score 3):

First of all you are using c++, so let's use std::string, and use classes. Lets create Athlete struct which contains everything your athlete needs:

```
struct Athlete {
    Athlete() = default;
    Athlete(std::stringstream &stream) {
        stream >> firstName 
               >> lastName 
               >> athleteNumber 
               >> country 
               >> athleteTime;
    }
    // every Athlete is unique, copying should be prohibited
    Athlete(const Athlete&) = delete;

    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    std::string athleteNumber;
    std::string country;
    std::string athleteTime;
}
```

Maybe you could work on this one a bit more and encapsulate it better.

now we will use std::vector to store Athletes and every time we push_back we will call Athelete constructor with read line from input file. Later on you can use range-based for loop to access every single Athlete in vector. Also note that ifstream doesn't to be closed manually, it is closed automatically as soon as object reaches out of scope.

```
void readInputFromFile() {
   ifstream inputData("Athlete info.txt");
   std::vector<Athlete> athletes;

   std::string line;
   std::stringstream ss;

   if (inputData.is_open() {
      while (getline(inputData, line)) {
         ss.str(line);
         // directly construct in-place
         athletes.emplace_back(ss);
      }

      for (const Athlete& a : athletes) {
         /* ...*/
      }
   } else {
      std:cerr << "ERROR" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I did not know you could pass a `std::stringstream` to `getline`. I'll be using this in my own code!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It contains a lot of what I haven't done yet, so I'm finding it a little confusing, but thanks nonetheless!

Comment: Don't worry to ask anything, i will gladly help to bring understanfin upon yourself

Comment: You've prohibited copying and perform `push_back` on `Athlete` object. This seems a bit controversial to me. I think you should use `emplace_back`. (Yes, I know the compiler will call the move constructor anyway, this just seems more logical).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest change would be

```
while(inputData >> firstName[i])
{
    inputData >> lastName[i]; 
    inputData >> athleteNumber[i];
    inputData >> country[i]; 
    inputData >> athleteTime[i];
    i++;
    numOfCharacters++;
}
```

This would rely on the  input being correctly formatted.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't save the firstName Peter in firstName[0]. This is because when I later cout << firstName[0] I get weird values or nothing at all.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange! I'm sure I tested it and it worked… However @Marzi's answer is the better answer, if you're able to depart from the styles of old textbooks.